# How to minimize my query to fast the query time in my navicat?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
SELECT
    zxc.alias1,
    zxc.alias2
FROM
    (SELECT p.id,
   (SELECT i.column
      FROM table i
     WHERE i.column = p.column AND i.column <= 50
    ORDER BY i.column DESC
     LIMIT 1)
      AS alias1,
                (SELECT i.column
      FROM table i
     WHERE i.column = p.column AND i.column <= 50
    ORDER BY i.column DESC
     LIMIT 1)
      AS alias2,
```

FROM table p WHERE p.column = 0  ) as zxc ORDER BY zxc.column DESC

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query. In addition, questions about query performance ALWAYS require the EXPLAIN for the given query.

Comment: Okay sir thank you

Comment: Also, the query above is gibberish, only capable of providing a syntax error (well, several syntax errors)

Comment: Okay sir thank you for your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this change-

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(zxc.id,',',zxc.status_id) AS id, 
    zxc.employee_name, 
    zxc.status, 
    zxc.working_days, 
    zxc.start_date, 
    zxc.status_id, 
    zxc.id as emp_id 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        p.id,
        CONCAT(p.last_name,', ',p.first_name,' ',IFNULL(p.middle_name,'')) as employee_name,
        i.start_date,
        i.working_days,
        i.status,
        i.id as status_id
    FROM employees p
    INNER JOIN employees_default_shifts i ON i.employee_id = p.id AND i.start_date <= '2019-10-10'
    WHERE p.is_deleted = 0
    ORDER BY i.start_date DESC LIMIT 1
) as zxc 
ORDER BY zxc.start_date DESC
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your help. But null values is not showing using this i want to include even null values.

Comment: Which column has Null values? Can you add some data in your problem description and also add output required.

Comment: Sir i have a problem in inner join the result in the table is not match in my old query.

Comment: @SE.Edward Please add some sample data in your question description.Also, you have updated your original question query, it is totally different from what I'm trying to improve.

Comment: Hi sir this is my Original Code
 SELECT zxc.id AS id, zxc.working_days, zxc.start_date, zxc.id as emp_id FROM (SELECT p.id as id, (SELECT i.start_date FROM employees_default_shifts i WHERE i.employee_id = p.id AND i.start_date <= '{$date}' ORDER BY i.start_date DESC LIMIT 1) AS start_date, (SELECT i.working_days FROM employees_default_shifts i WHERE i.employee_id = p.id AND i.start_date <= '{$date}' ORDER BY i.start_date DESC LIMIT 1) AS working_days FROM employees p WHERE p.is_deleted = 0  AND p.department_id = '{$dep_id}') as zxc ORDER BY zxc.start_date DESC

Comment: My problem is i cant get the max or the latest data if i use inner join so i find the solution to select it one by one then i order by desc the table and get the first line but the problem is the query execution is too slow to execute the query.

Comment: You can test `Left Join` instead of `Inner join`. You can always create new question with new requirement.